# import excel csv file into heidiSQL

Tags: excel, csv, import, heidisql

I used this query to import data to my database in HeidiSQL;

```
LOAD DATA INFILE registration.csv

INTO TABLE registration

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

(@id, @date, @method, @stud_id, @staff_id)

SET

registration_Id     = (CASE WHEN @id='' THEN NULL ELSE @id END),

registration_Date   = (CASE WHEN @date='' THEN NULL ELSE @date END),

payment_Method = (CASE WHEN @method='' THEN NULL ELSE @method END),

student_Id    = (CASE WHEN @stud_id='' THEN NULL ELSE @stud_id END),

staff_Id    = (CASE WHEN @staff_id='' THEN NULL ELSE @staff_id END);
```

But I don't know where to save my registration.csv file and it cause an error.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can place the file somewhere on your client computer, and modify your query in the following way:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\to\\file.csv' INTO TABLE...
```

This might not work if the server variable "local_infile" is disabled.

Comment: @siti nazirah: did that work for you? If yes, please vote for the reply.